# How do I add my application in the Default Programs list

Tags: c#, windows, registry, file-association

I want to add my application in the Default Programs list and read articles and questions like these:
[How do I add my application in the Default Programs list of Windows Vista/7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542354/how-do-i-add-my-application-in-the-default-programs-list-of-windows-vista-7)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
and do all of theme but no chance.
I make registry keys like these:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   SOFTWARE
      Classes
         TestApp.AssocFile.TA4
            (Default) = TA4 Format
            DefaultIcon
               (Default) = %ProgramFiles%\TestApp\TA4.ico
            shell
               open
                  command
                     (Default) = %ProgramFiles%\TestApp\TA4Opener.exe


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   SOFTWARE
      Test
         TestApp
            Capabilities
               ApplicationDescription = App Description 
               FileAssociations
                  .ta4 = TestApp.AssocFile.TA4


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   SOFTWARE
      RegisteredApplications
         TestApp = Software\Test\TestApp\Capabilities
```

but when I open Control Panel Set Default programs I can't find my application.
What I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ApplicationName` value under Capabilities, in addition to all values you already have.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  SOFTWARE
    Test
      TestApp
        Capabilities
          ApplicationName = Your Application Name
```

If your application still does not show up in the Set Default Programs list, make sure executable file listed under shell\open\command ( in your example, %ProgramFiles%\TestApp\TA4Opener.exe) has Version resource and `Version.CompanyName` is not empty.

Comment: I added ApplicationName.Can you give me an example about version?

Comment: Double click .rc file in Resource Files folder in Solution explorer. In Resource View,  if you don't see Version folder, right click the project node and do Add - Resource, select Version,  fill in the fields, at least Company Name. build. test.

Comment: Just one problem is application has not any icon and I added DefaultIcon key and set it value to icon address.

Comment: Sure but still application has not any icon and I wait until have an complete answer.Do you have an idea?

Comment: Does %ProgramFiles%\TestApp\TA4Opener.exe have an icon? if not, add it, similar to adding a version resource.

Comment: Sure it have but no icon in Default application list!

Comment: try replacing value of DefaultIcon with `%ProgramFiles%\TestApp\TA4Opener.exe,0`

Comment: Now it works,thank you.I will update your answer and accept it.

Comment: @ara deonas: since you're interested in complete solution, one more thing you can add to your program is the web site URL. it would appear under your program in Default Programs list. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27446817/3220060