# Properly registering an application that handles websites with windows

Tags: windows, wix, file-association

My use of several browsers for different purposes has caused me to be displeased with how windows 10 handles your default browser choice, so I decided to make a small application so I can pick the browser I want, or use the one open browser, if there is one.

I have though ran into a bit of a problem getting my app into the list of applications in the settings app.

Source code is available here: https://github.com/mortenn/BrowserPicker

In particular, the registry values I have tried setting are listed in the wix file here: https://github.com/mortenn/BrowserPicker/blob/master/Setup/Product.wxs

I based these keys on the answer here: [How to associate application with existing file types using WiX installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772452/how-to-associate-application-with-existing-file-types-using-wix-installer) as well as looking at how firefox/ie had their keys set up.

I also found this question, [How do I add my application in the Default Programs list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375774/how-do-i-add-my-application-in-the-default-programs-list) which also mentions that company must be set, which I have now done as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the mistake. After removing "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" from my registry values, it started working.
See this commit for the details: https://github.com/mortenn/BrowserPicker/commit/f92e275d3e4d1cd8e7f05554037cfb702b7cfafb